# Add value in user table when user is created

Tags: users, user-registration

I am trying to insert a value into a column after a user registers.

Sadly after my test I get the error "Write Error" what could be wrong with the hook?

````
function org_teammember( $user_id ) {
    $teammember = 'yes';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (ocp_team_member)".
    "VALUES('$user_id','$teammember')";

    $result = mysqli_query($wpdb, $sql) or die('Write Error!');

 }```
````

Comment: Why don't you just use a function WordPress already has `update_user_meta()`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/
There is no need to write a custom SQL queries

Comment: Thank you very much @geouser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the method of @geouser

> Why don't you just use a function WordPress already has
> update_user_meta()?
> developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta There is
> no need to write a custom SQL queries